# Are there any recognized math certificates I can take to show self learned math knowledge for an application?

Tags: exams

That's it. Any exam I could just sit and prove I know math beyond the courses I took so I can show an education institution my level is higher than what you could get from my CV?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what level you are looking for? E.g., "math PhD applications", "computer science masters applications", "undergraduate applications", etc.

Comment: Your other question probably offers a better path.

Comment: The GRE Math exam, maybe? (or the SATs for a lower-level test)